# Does uniform hyperbolicity requires both or any of the stable and unstable spaces?

Tags: dynamical-systems

Consider the bernoulli shift map,

From the definition in [this article](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Hyperbolic_dynamics) in scholarpedia,

> We say that f is uniformly hyperbolic or an Anosov diffeomorphism if for every x∈M there is a splitting of the tangent space $T_xM=E^s(x)⊕E^u(x)$

The question is weather the definition of uniformly hyperbolic system requires the splitting of the tangent space to have *both* stable and unstable spaces, or if it can just contain the unstable space (e.g. the case of the Bernoulli shift).

My understanding is that  it is hyperbolic if the dimension of the centered space is 0, which supports the idea that it *does not required both* spaces, but the definition in the article seems to be ambiguous in that respect. The definition in the book of Ott is also inconclusive to this discussion.

Comment: I think there's no need to have both of them,and it depends on your anosov diffeomorphism , it can just expand it's vectors or just contract them on its tangent space ,i mean there is no need to have both contraction and expansion ,it is not mentioned in any definition.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you are interested in an invertible dynamical system or not. If you have only (strong) expanding directions, for example you can hardly get something invertible.

But of course you can condier maps like $x\to 2 x (\mod 1)$ on the circle and call it hyperbolic (and chaotic).